# Javascript singleton dilema

Tags: javascript, singleton

I have a bit stupid question. For example, I have code like this:

```
class Database {
  constructor(name, password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;

    if (Database.instance) {
      return Database.instance;
    }

    Database.instance = this;
  }
}


const db1 = new Database('Valentino Rossi', '987654321');
const db2 = new Database('Jonh Doe', '1234567890');
console.log(db1 === db2); // true
```

This console.log will return true so this is a singleton.
But if I change the only place where I define Database.instance = this; like below, it won't work.
Can you explain to me why this happens, please?

```
class Database {
  constructor(name, password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;

    Database.instance = this;

    if (Database.instance) {
      return Database.instance;
    }
  }
}


const db1 = new Database('Valentino Rossi', '987654321');
const db2 = new Database('Jonh Doe', '1234567890');
console.log(db1 === db2); // false
```

Comment: The second always changes the content of `Database.instance`. The first only once.

Answer (score 0):

Because you override `instance` every creation of Database and only after that check if `Database.instance` is truthy and of course it is so you return it (*new instance*)

Answer (score 0):

Because `instance` property stores link to primary created instance of `Database` class and by calling assignment `Database.instance = this;` before checking existense `instance` property you are overwriting existing reference to primary created instance, so subsequent checking of existence of `instance` property makes no sense, because new created instance returned.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, what you're doing is this: First creating an instance with `('Valentino Rossi', '987654321')`. Then, again creating another instance with `('Jonh Doe', '1234567890')`. Hence, both are different.

```
     //These two are different instances
    const db1 = new Database('Valentino Rossi', '987654321');
    const db2 = new Database('Jonh Doe', '1234567890');
     console.log(db1 === db2); // false
```

In the first case, you're returning straightway if an instance exist already. So second instance is not created with `('Jonh Doe', '1234567890')`